# Run slow background process when certain conditions in Postgres data are met?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, next.js, vercel, supabase

I'm using Postgres (via Supabase) and Node (via NextJS on Vercel).

I have a table `report` which has columns for an enum `region`, and `generated_text` which is content generated by AI.

```
create type region as enum (
  'America',
  'Europe',
  'Asia',
  'Africa'
);

create table report (
  id serial primary key,
  region region,
  generated_text: text
);
```

A user selects their region and then purchases a report. Purchases are recorded in a join-table `report_user`.

```
create table report_user(
  id serial primary key,
  report uuid NOT NULL,
  user: uuid NOT NULL
)
```

When the user makes a purchase:

- If there is a row in the `report` table for that region which the user hasn't purchased before then that row is returned to them.
- If there isn't a report for that region, or if the user has already purchased all of the reports for that region, then we need to create a new row. This requires a request to an AI API for the `generated_text` column which is very slow and is a bad user experience.

I'd like to improve the speed for users and this can only be done by creating `report` rows before they are needed. I can bulk-create some but I don't know which regions will be more popular (I've simplified my example, my actual application has many more filters and thus a lot of potential combinations).

Is there a way to run a background task to create a new `report`  when the user has purchased all `report` rows for a certain `region` filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to run a background task to create...when...

Yes, there is - and you don't even need to take one step outside Supabase.

It offers [`http` extension](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/extensions/http) which lets you run the API request to get new reports to top up your inventory when you run low, straight from a [`trigger`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html), in SQL. There's even [`pg_net`](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/extensions/pg_net) that does that asynchronously. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/T8UYo4cA)

Set up a table you insert a row into whenever someone orders a report:

```sql
create table orders(id int generated always as identity primary key,
                    "user" uuid references users(uid), 
                    region region);
```

Another one with parameters dictating when you want to restock reports for each `region`:

```sql
create table report_stock_parameters as
select unnest(enum_range(null::region)) as region, 
       3 as min_stock_size,
       4 as restock_batch_size;
```

You can place the criteria telling you when to restock, in a function:

```sql
create function is_restock_required(p_user uuid,p_region region)
returns boolean as $f$
    select (select min_stock_size 
            from report_stock_parameters
            where region=p_region) 
          >(select count(*) --counting reports unused by the user
            from report 
            left join report_user
                   on report.id=report_user.report
                  and report.region=p_region
                  and report_user.user=p_user
            where report_user.id is null) --anti-join
$f$ language sql;
```

Finally, the procedure that calls the API to restock reports:

```sql
create procedure fetch_some_more_reports(p_region region)as $f$
    insert into report (region,generated_text)
    select p_region, (response."content")::jsonb #>> '{path,to,report}'
    from generate_series(1,(select restock_batch_size 
                            from report_stock_parameters
                            where region=p_region))as a(g1),
         http_get('https://generative_ai_api.com/reports/please',
                   jsonb_build_object('access_token', 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV',
                                      'throwaway', g1))as response;
$f$ language sql;
```

The trigger that fires in response to inserts of new, incoming orders, and when you need a refill, runs the restocking procedure:

```sql
create function trgf_restock_reports()returns trigger as $f$
begin 
    call fetch_some_more_reports(new.region);
    return null;
end $f$ language plpgsql;

create trigger t_report_stock_monitor after insert on orders
for each row when (is_restock_required(new.user,new.region))
execute function trgf_restock_reports();
```

Depending on how your API wants you to authenticate, you'd change sending the `access_token` in payload to passing a key in a header, URL parameter, etc. See [examples on the extension's GitHub](https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-http?tab=readme-ov-file#examples).

I'm stuffing `g1` value from `generate_series()` in the `http_get()` call to prevent the db from evaluating it only once and re-using for each of the reports you want to generate in a batch during refill. The dependency communicates that you want to fetch a new report, that many times.

Your API might offer a method of requesting multiple in one request, in which case you'd skip `generate_series()`, pass `restock_batch_size` directly into the request, then split the response with [`jsonb_array_elements_text()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) into separate rows.

---

1. Supabase also supports [`pg_cron` extension](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/extensions/pg_cron) you can use to set up recurring jobs, also right in the db. A `trigger` soudns better because it'll fire anytime someone orders a report and immediately fetch reports from the API to re-stock. A recurring, time-based `pg_cron` job would run the risk that sometimes you'd run out and have to wait some time before it checks in to re-stock according to the schedule.
2. If it was your own, plain PostgreSQL, you could use a [Steampipe](https://steampipe.io/) plugin for the API you're getting the reports from, which hide away all the details of API-calling logic, expose it as a table, and translate your simple selects from it into API calls, then translates the responses into rows as if they came from a table.

   There are [existing, off-the-shelf Steampipe plugins](https://hub.steampipe.io/plugins) for generative AI ([CohereAI](https://hub.steampipe.io/plugins/mr-destructive/cohereai), [OpenAI](https://hub.steampipe.io/plugins/turbot/openai)) you can use:

   ```sql
   select completion
   from openai_completion
   where prompt = 'Write a tagline for an ice cream shop.';
   ```

   | completion |
   | --- |
   | 1. Cool down with a scoop of our delicious ice cream! 2. Indulge your cravings with creamy goodness! 3. Sweeten your day with a scoop of our tasty treats! |

   If you're using some other service, you'd have to build your own Steampipe wrapper for it.

   In Supabase you can't add full-sized Steampipe, but you can have Steampipe running elsewhere and link its API-caller-disguised-as-a-table through [`postgres_fdw`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) as a [`foreign table`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createforeigntable.html). This would give you a completely declarative, pure SQL, in-db solution, possibly offloading API handling to Steampipe, with the caveat of requiring two db's: `pg_cron` schedule or trigger-based logic on Supabase dictates when to run a refill, which it does by just running a select from the other, linked db, where Steampipe translates that to an API call.
3. Supabase also has its own [`wrappers` framework](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/extensions/wrappers/overview) which offers a similar approach to Steampipe. It has only [12 readily available](https://github.com/supabase/wrappers) options and none for generative AI (compared to Steampipe's 140, with 2 of those), but it's *native*, so it might be a better choice if you were to try and build your own API-wrapping-extension. It would appear that there might be a way you could build a ["Steampipe postgres fdw"](https://steampipe.io/docs/steampipe_postgres/install) and [add that to Supabase](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/extensions?database-method=dashboard) but it seems Supabase only welcomes plain SQL or PL/pgSQL extensions from outside their [pre-configured list](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/extensions#full-list-of-extensions), and the Steampipe-generated FDW is a bit more complex than that.
4. It could be a good idea to collect stats who and how often needs a refill and increase the parameter dictating how far ahead of their demand you want to stay. Depending on how the API works, what traffic you're taking and your storage/db config, you might want to let the trigger categorise users into green, yellow and red groups, and *not* refill anyone's reports when they only drop from green to yellow, but as soon as at least one runs red, run a single bulk refill for everyone in either yellow or red. One large request and one large `insert` every now and then, replacing a continuous stream of tiny ones.